flutter IntrinsicWidth ListView.builder
although IntrinsicWidth works with Column, i am not being able to make it work with ListView.builder. maybe i can wrap the Column with SingleChildScrollView, but that's anothe story, does it work with ListView.builder ?
here is my code:
// IntrinsicWidth not working with ListView
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main(){
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return const MaterialApp(
      home: HomeScreen(),
    );
  }
}

class HomeScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  const HomeScreen({super.key});
  @override
  State<HomeScreen> createState() => _HomeScreenState();
}

class _HomeScreenState extends State<HomeScreen> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(title: const Text('app'),backgroundColor: Colors.blue,),
      body: Center(
        child: IntrinsicWidth(
          child: ListView.builder(
            //physics: const NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
            itemCount: ls.length,
            itemBuilder: (context, index){
              return Center(
                child: Container(
                  color: Colors.yellow.shade200,
                  margin: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 2),
                  child: Text(ls[index],style: const TextStyle(fontSize: 30)),
                ),
              );
            },
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
List<String> ls =[
  "John Doe",
  "Jane Smith",
  "Michael Johnson",
  "Emily Davis",
  "William Brown",
  "Olivia Taylor",
  "James Wilson",
  "Emma Jones",
  "Oliver Carter",
  "Ava Lee",
];

i get the following errors:
/*
The following assertion was thrown during performLayout():
RenderViewport does not support returning intrinsic dimensions.
*/
/*
The following assertion was thrown during performLayout():
'package:flutter/src/rendering/shifted_box.dart': Failed assertion: line 345 pos 12: 'child!.hasSize': is not true.
*/

intrinsic width is not relevant to listview.builder because the concept of intrinsic width is the natural width a widget would take based on its content isn't relevant for scrollable widgets like ListView, as they expand to fill the available space. instead of
you should use shrinkWrap. just add shrinkWrap: true in listview.builder
